# Wrap serialized JSON string in single quotes due to issue parsing with double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to use `JSON.stringfy()` and `JSON.parse()` to  serialize and deserialize JSON. It's working fine with a single quoted serialized string but I cannot parse a double quoted serialized string as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Surely this is only a problem if you're using a string literal, in which case you can manually change the quotes...? It would help to see the code which generates the JSON.

Comment: JSON format uses double quotes internally.  You'll need to wrap it in single quotes (or escape every `"` inside the JSON string.)

Comment: `var json = "text"` and `var json = 'text'` are equivalent, so if you do `JSON.parse(json)` you won't have problems.

Comment: [When we ask a question about a problem with our code, we have to let the people who are helping us see it. Images of our code do not qualify.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] demonstrating your actual problem. You said you were using `JSON.stringify`, but your screenshot appears to show manually constructed string literals.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your response , Can't we stringfy json object with single quote?, it's a dynamic object so, changing manually may not be efficient.

Comment: @DanielBeck i tried by replacing double quote insidethe json string with single one, but it doesnot work too.

Comment: @BPun no, JSON is only valid when double quotes are used to delimit keys and values.

Comment: If you are doing some php/javascript combo stuff or similar, rather than `var a = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($b);?>');`, where `$b` contains a single quote/apostrophe, try using `var a = <?php echo json_encode($b);?>;`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but as in the above shapshot i just change the double quote of stringfied string generated by json.stringfy with single one it's working fine.

Comment: @vlaz neither of those will work because `text` on its own is not valid JSON. http://jsfiddle.net/7d1z6fmp/

Comment: @BPun I think you're referring to the outer quote marks which tells JavaScript that that's the start and end of the string variable which contains the JSON. Rory is talking about the quote marks which actually form a part of the JSON. The JSON itself cannot have property names or strings wrapped in single quotes, that's invalid. But you can write a string literal in JS wrapped in single quotes, which is what your first example is doing. That's absolutely fine. The second one doesn't work because JS doesn't know where the string literal starts and ends, due to the other double quotes.

Comment: @ADyson I was trying to be concise in a comment but sure, if you wish - `"text"` and `'text'` will result in the EXACT same string, regardless of the quote marks used. So if OP uses single quotes for the string, then `JSON.parse` would work the same way. Therefore, there is no need to use double quotes. I didn't want to write all this because I didn't expect people to nitpick

Comment: @vlaz ok but if you're going to include an example about parsing JSON to someone who's having trouble parsing JSON then it would make sense to include some valid JSON in the example...it can still be quite brief JSON :-). And it won't always work the exact same way anyway, because it tends to depend on the content of the string. JSON contains a lot of double-quotes usually, so unless you're going to escape them first, there's a good chance it'll fall over unless the string literal is enclosed in single quotes. That's kinda the whole point of the thread.

Comment: @ADyson exactly sir, you got me. but how can i wrap string with single quote while using json.stringfy

Comment: @BPun In a real-life situation I don't really see why you'd need to - normally you'd be dealing with somet data which was already in a variable. The single quotes are really only a problem if for some reason you hard-coded the JSON string

Comment: @ADyson i just want to store json object in DOM, and manupulate it later

Comment: @BPun what's the point of that? You can just store it as an _object_, not a _string_. JSON is only useful really as a way to transmit data, or store it in some persistent location. If you're planning to hold data in memory during the life of the application, just store it as a normal variable.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your response, actually i have list of json object , and i want to store all the information in json form some where in dom and take back later.

Comment: i use the $('<input type = "text" id="hdn_' + count + '_' + index + '_'  + '">').data.key = result; inside for loop to store data but i override the previous one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182996/discussion-between-bpun-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have quotes inside quotes. The solution of this problem is using type of quotes different from the quotes inside, so if you have a string like: I'm studying you should write "I'm studying" and not 'I'm studying'.

An other way to avoid this problem is using the escape character \ .
So you should write 'I\'m studying'.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) you can find some documentation.